# Codeigniter add space in query that's why it return wrong total + mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have to count commaseprated values from my table for that i run this query

```
$this->db->select('*,
        LENGTH(members_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(members_id,",","")) + 2 as total',false);
        $query = $this->db->get('group');
        $res = $query->result_array();
```

> when it execute query it should be like  LENGTH(REPLACE(members_id,",",""))
>
> but it add space near "," and chage it to ", "
>
> after added space query will look like LENGTH(REPLACE(members_id,",
>   ",""))
>   so it return wrong value

i want query like :

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(members_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(members_id, ",", "")) + 2 as total FROM (`group`)
```

but it change it to

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(members_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(members_id, ", ", "")) + 2 as total FROM (`group`)
```

Comment: LENGTH(REPLACE(members_id,",","") replace the single quotes with double quotes ' to "

Comment: i already try this it won't work

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh i am using mysql

Comment: Have you tried writing the entire query using $query = $this->db->query() ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TRIM()` mysql function for search keyword of "," inside the REPLACE.

Correct format is : `LENGTH(REPLACE(members_id,TRIM(","),""))`

I faced this problem in the past, then, I used the `$this->db->query()` with the mysql statement. Now I have found the solution :) It's working fine (y)